# Imgur - URL is from image ID

Tags: url, imgur

New here - and new to all of this. I am looking for a way to have my images searched based on the ID of the image uploaded.

Eg.
**Image ID:** 000217
****Current URL:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ROkb.jpg
Goal URL:** https://imgur.com/00217

If I need an album identifier or any other identifier that can stay constant so I can view specific images based on image ID that would be the goal.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't understand your actual goal, the URL with `00217` is 404 Not Found on imgur. The id of the image is `HSfWUdP` not `00217`.

Comment: The goal of this is to have a structured URL with the specific image ID as the identifier. Basically, I am using Imgur or an image hosting site to host all my website photos. The photos will then be pulled based off their matching ID which is the same as the image names. the URL with 00217 currently does not exist as I'm trying to achieve something similar to that since 000217 is the image ID uploaded to imgur.

Comment: So you have a local database on your server/computer and there is an entry with id `217` that is mapping to imgur img id `HSfWUdP`?

Comment: When you go to the [imgur API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/), you can see the imgur image id is not a decimal but a string `HSfWUdP`. `00217` is not a valid imgur image ID.